# CSS - Div's are running off page on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the below set of code. It works fine in most browsers. But I noticed on my main Galaxy S5 browser (which I'm sure affects other browsers also), the two images run off the page. I would appreciate any help. I know the answer may be simple, but after trying a 100 things over a few days, I believe I just have an unnecessary value somewhere and I accidentally merged two solutions.

Thanks,

```css
.arrow {
  width: 21px;
  height: 57px;
}
.pagination {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.pagination_sub {
  width: 700px;
  height: 57px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.pagination_pre {
  width: 410px;
  height: 57px;
}
.greypagination {
  width: 33px;
  height: 57px;
}
.prearrow {
  width: 12px;
  height: 57px;
}
.prepagination {
  width: 44px;
  height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="pagination_sub">
    <div class="pagination_pre"></div>
    <div class="prepagination">
      <img src="../images/pgpage.jpg" width="44" height="57" />
    </div>
    <div class="greypagination">
      <img src="../images/pg1-grey.jpg" width="33" height="57" />
    </div>
    <div class="greypagination">
      <img src="../images/pg2-blank.jpg" width="33" height="57" />
    </div>
    <div class="prearrow"></div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <img src="../images/pgarrow.jpg" width="21" height="57" border="0" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide us with an image link reproducing the problem? It's hard to grasp otherwise. Also, what are the steps you've already tried?

Comment: Which two images? In your markup, you have four images. None of them is wider than 44px.

Comment: Did you try using 'em' instead of 'px' for your CSS image measurements?